# forward declaration of classes, splitting variables and functions

Tags: c++, class, dependencies, declaration, forward

Let's assume I have two classes A and B in C++. Both classes have some private variables and both are friends. Both classes have some simple public function (no function call in these functions), that uses variables from both A and B.

I give you an code-example of the idea:

```
    class A;
    class B;

    //Here I declare the variables

    class A{
        friend class B;
        private:
        double a=2.;
        };

    class B{
        friend class A;
        private:
        double b=2.;
        };

    //Now I try to declare the functions
    //I know, I do a redefinition now, but actually I just 
    //like to define the functions after the variables, such
    //that the compiler knows the variables my functions 
    //like to use.

   class A{
        public:
        double fun(B Btest){return Btest.b+2*a;}    
        };

    class B{
        public:
        double fun(A Atest){return Atest.a+b;}  
        };


    int main(){

        A Atest;
        B Btest;

        double s=Btest.fun(Atest);
        return 0;
        }
```

If I were the compiler, I also would not accept that code because there might be ugly circular dependencies, but in my case, I am sure, there are no circles. Is there a nice way to tell my compiler to do something like this?

Here is the solution, I didn't really understood the concept of declaration and definition in detail:

[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

```
    class A;
    class B;

    class A{
        friend class B;
        public:
        double fun(B);
        private:
        double a=2.;
        };

  class B{
       friend class A;
       public:
       double fun(A);   
       private:
       double b=2.;
    };

    double A::fun(B Btest){return Btest.b+a;} 
    double B::fun(A Atest){return Atest.a+b;}   

    int main(){

        A Atest;
        B Btest;

        double s=Btest.fun(Atest);
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: You can't re-define classes just because you think that's how the syntax should work.

Comment: My compiler tells me: error: redefinition of ‘class A’

Comment: Sander De Dycker is just kind of right, the problem was in forward declaration. This site showed me the solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function